# Getting a number from within a URL

Tags: javascript, regex, selenium-ide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get query string values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

I am trying to get a page number from a URL during a test. The URL looks like this:

http://www.site.com/objects/search/8765XX/results?page=2&sort_att=posted_dt&sort_dir=desc

What I want to get is the page number right after 'page=' in the url.

Comment: Answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one line, by splitting url. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TdS78/)

```
var url = "http://www.site.com/objects/search/8765XX/results?page=2&sort_att=posted_dt&sort_dir=desc";

var pageNumber = parseInt(url.split("page=")[1].split("&")[0], 10);
```

Comment: When I put this into Selenium-IDE, i get Null for the value of 'num' (I previously stored the url into a variable called 'url'. 

storeEval | var url = storedVars['url']; var pageNumber = parseInt(url.split("page=")[1].split("&")[0], 10); | num

Comment: Okay, got it to work.  Using this in Selenium IDE

storeEval | javascript{storedVars['V1'].split("page=")[1].split("&")[0];} | num

num gets me the page number.

Answer (score 0):

I have this small function to fetch URL parameters (I found it on internet many years ago) :

```
function getUrlParameter(name, defaultValue) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
    if( results == null ) return defaultValue;
    else return results[1];
}
```

I use it like this :

```
pageNumber = parseInt(getUrlParameter('page'), 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple pure JavaScript implementation I can think of would be something like the following:

```
 var url = http://www.site.com/objects/search/8765XX/results?page=2&sort_att=posted_dt&sort_dir=desc
 var matchedPos =  url.search("page=\\d");
 var matched = url.substr(matchedPos);
 var num = matched.split("=")[1]; //might need to parse
```